# How to get term name with link for specific ids

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to display custom category on archive page.

```
$term_id_array= array(1,2,4,50);
```

how to retrieve the term name with link for these term_ids

My custom post_type name = product
taxonomy = product_cat

Note: I am using woocommerce.

Please help I am trying this code to display all product category name as a list

```
<?php 
$taxonomy = 'product_cat'; //Choose the taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy ); //Get all the terms
foreach ($terms as $term) { //Cycle through terms, one at a time
$term_id = $term->term_id; //Define the term ID
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); 
$term_name = $term->name;
echo '<p class="list-cat"><span>' . $term_id . '</span> -<span>' . $term_name . '</span></p>';  
}
?>
```

**Out put:**

1- Clothing
2- Shirt
3- Pant
4- Lady's Pant
5- T-shirt
6........
.......
5- Sun Glass

But How can I get Name with link for this `1,2,4,50` IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) accept an array of arguments as second parameter. One of those parameters are `include`

> **`include`**
>
> (integer) An array of term ids to include. Empty returns all.

You already have your selected term ids in an array, so just simply pass them to the `include` parameter in the array of arguments in `get_terms()`

```
$terms =  get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'include' => $term_id_array ) );
```

or with short araay syntax (*availble since PHP 5.4*)

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, ['include' => $term_id_array] );
```

Comment: How I get them as a list?  Can you please show me example code? I am new in this field.

Comment: I don't understand, you need to change `$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );` in your code with my code; `$terms =  get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'include' => $term_id_array ) );` where you have already defined `$term_id_array` as `$term_id_array= array(1,2,4,50);`

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked out. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: could you please help me [This Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196642/how-to-remove-custom-post-type-slug-taxonomy-base-from-url-in-wordpress)